# opening flask to more ports

Tags: python, linux, port, google-compute-engine

flask default port is 5000, I'm working with compute engine and testing my service from my local machine browser, for that i've added to the app.run function the parameter `host = '0.0.0.0'`. I execute the script and my simple hello world service runs, I've read i can give a specific port by adding the parameter port to the app.run command so now it looks like this: `app.run(host = '0.0.0.0' , port=5050 , debug = True)` it executes fine

```
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5050/
* Restarting with reloader
```

but when i call it from the browser i get the error `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to <compute engine instance external ip>:5050`

do i need to "open" port 5050 and if so where and how

Comment: Where are you running the instance you want to connect to? Is it a local instance, or a deployed AWS compute engine instance with attached external IP (which costs extra)?

Comment: @VooDooNOFX compute engine is the IAAS of google not related to AWS of amazon, I have an instance on google cloud, where my flask service is running from my macbook browser i'm trying to connect to the URI exposed by my service

Comment: Right, then your Google Compute instance's firewall is likely the culprit. That's all I got though.

Comment: @VooDooNOFX you are right! I had to enter a firewall rule for the new port

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking.

It should explain in some gory detail how to connect a google compute engine to the outside world, and to configure firewalls to allow connections.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a google compute connection but flask as it works fine on port 5000,